# Permission error in Apache server

Tags: linux, apache, iframe

I have the following IFrame:

```
<iframe src='http://example.com/widget_r" width="650" height="4000" frameborder="0"  scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

it works fine on localhost but when it is online it stops working giving me this message:

```
You don't have permission to access /widget_r" width="650" height="4000" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe></div></aside></div><!-- on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I know nothing at all about Apache control and permissions so please help me
what does that error means? and can i solve this problem or i should change the Iframe concept??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is malformed.

You have

```
<iframe src='http://example.com/widget_r" width="650" height="4000" frameborder="0"  scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

change the `src='` to `src="`.

Comment: The clue was that the error message "You don't have permission to access /widget_r" width="650" height="4000" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe></div></aside></div><!-- on this server." showed that it was trying to fetch `/widget_r" width="650" height="4000" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe></div></aside></div><!--` as a filename.

Comment: i realize that after seeing your answer :)